# Create map with parent key and filter data from object push it to the map- Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

```js
    con_data = {
      "0": {
        "Actual1920": 2379403,
        "Budget1920": 10121051.161450788,
        "CostOwner": "Dr. Ratnavat",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Salary",
        "LedgereType": "Salary-Teaching",
        "RemainingAmount": 7741648.161450788,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "1": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 0,
        "CostOwner": "Dr. Ratnavat",
        "LedgerBudget": "Salary",
        "LedgerType": "Salary-Teaching",
        "RemainingAmount": 0
      },
      "2": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 0,
        "CostOwner": "Dr. Ratnavat",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Salary",
        "LedgereType": "Salary-Contract & Professional",
        "RemainingAmount": 0,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "3": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 540098.7555555556,
        "CostOwner": "Vineeta S",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Admission",
        "LedgereType": "Admission-Referral",
        "RemainingAmount": 540098.7555555556,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "4": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 40835.600000000006,
        "CostOwner": "Vineeta S",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Admission",
        "LedgereType": "Admission-Others",
        "RemainingAmount": 40835.600000000006,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "5": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 1690058.304,
        "CostOwner": "Nitin P",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Advertisement",
        "LedgereType": "Advertisement- Print & Others",
        "RemainingAmount": 1690058.304,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "6": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 1115690.5056,
        "CostOwner": "Nitin P",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Advertisement",
        "LedgereType": "Advertisement- Web",
        "RemainingAmount": 1115690.5056,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "7": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 223245.79200000002,
        "CostOwner": "Nitin P",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Advertisement",
        "LedgereType": "Advertisement -Printing Production",
        "RemainingAmount": 223245.79200000002,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "8": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 300000,
        "CostOwner": "Vineeta S",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Marketing",
        "LedgereType": "Marketing",
        "RemainingAmount": 300000,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "9": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 764652.7777777778,
        "CostOwner": "Vineeta S",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Scholarship & Discounts",
        "LedgereType": "Scholarship & Discount",
        "RemainingAmount": 764652.7777777778,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "10": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 155843.62536,
        "CostOwner": "Jay S",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Aicte & Other Affiliation",
        "LedgereType": "Aicte & Other Affiliation",
        "RemainingAmount": 155843.62536,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "11": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 0,
        "CostOwner": "Dr. Ratnavat",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Foreign Affiliation",
        "LedgereType": "Foreign Affiliation",
        "RemainingAmount": 0,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "12": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 230132.22222222222,
        "CostOwner": "Dr. Ratnavat",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Book/Tool Kits",
        "LedgereType": "Book/Tool Kits",
        "RemainingAmount": 230132.22222222222,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "13": {
        "Actual1920": 3000,
        "Budget1920": 711156.6,
        "CostOwner": "Dr. Ratnavat",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Honorarium",
        "LedgereType": "Honorarium",
        "RemainingAmount": 708156.6,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "14": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 50000,
        "CostOwner": "Dr. Ratnavat",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Student Activity",
        "LedgereType": "Student Activity-Alumini",
        "RemainingAmount": 50000,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "15": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 5000,
        "CostOwner": "Dr. Ratnavat",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Student Activity",
        "LedgereType": "Student Activity-Convocation",
        "RemainingAmount": 5000,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "16": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": -2444.4444444444443,
        "CostOwner": "Dr. Ratnavat",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Student Activity",
        "LedgereType": "Student Activity-Examination",
        "RemainingAmount": -2444.4444444444443,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "17": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 50000,
        "CostOwner": "Dr. Ratnavat",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Student Activity",
        "LedgereType": "Student Activity-Seminar",
        "RemainingAmount": 50000,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "18": {
        "Actual1920": 26880,
        "Budget1920": 21374.222222222223,
        "CostOwner": "Dr. Ratnavat",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Student Activity",
        "LedgereType": "Student Activity-Inauguration",
        "RemainingAmount": -5505.777777777777,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "19": {
        "Actual1920": 177000,
        "Budget1920": 349402.77777777775,
        "CostOwner": "Dr. Ratnavat",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Student Activity",
        "LedgereType": "Student Activity-Induction",
        "RemainingAmount": 172402.77777777775,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "20": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 25000,
        "CostOwner": "Dr. Ratnavat",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Student Activity",
        "LedgereType": "Student Activity-Placement",
        "RemainingAmount": 25000,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "21": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 20746,
        "CostOwner": "Dr. Ratnavat",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Student Activity",
        "LedgereType": "Student Activity-Student Practical",
        "RemainingAmount": 20746,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "22": {
        "Actual1920": 3411,
        "Budget1920": 20187,
        "CostOwner": "Dr. Ratnavat",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Student Activity",
        "LedgereType": "Student Activity-Student related other Expenses",
        "RemainingAmount": 16776,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "23": {
        "Actual1920": 11310,
        "Budget1920": 110008.33333333331,
        "CostOwner": "Dr. Ratnavat",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Membership & Subscription",
        "LedgereType": "Membership & Subscription",
        "RemainingAmount": 98698.33333333331,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "24": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 170080.88888888888,
        "CostOwner": "Dr. Ratnavat",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Uniform",
        "LedgereType": "Uniform",
        "RemainingAmount": 170080.88888888888,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "25": {
        "Actual1920": 51669,
        "Budget1920": 177297.12000000002,
        "CostOwner": "Sandip S",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "House Keeping",
        "LedgereType": "House Keeping",
        "RemainingAmount": 125628.12000000002,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "26": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 0,
        "CostOwner": "Sandip S",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Hostel",
        "LedgereType": "Hostel-Canteen",
        "RemainingAmount": 0,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "27": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 0,
        "CostOwner": "Sandip S",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Hostel",
        "LedgereType": "Hostel-Other Consumables",
        "RemainingAmount": 0,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "28": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 536948,
        "CostOwner": "Sandip S",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Electricity",
        "LedgereType": "Electricity",
        "RemainingAmount": 536948,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },
      "29": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 255000,
        "CostOwner": "Sandip S",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Security",
        "LedgereType": "Security",
        "RemainingAmount": 255000,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
      },

    }


 this.new_data = Object.keys(this.con_data).reduce( (acc,currentKey)=>{
  const item = this.con_data[currentKey]
  const ledgetBudgetType = item.LedgerBudget
   if( !acc[ledgetBudgetType] ){
     acc[ledgetBudgetType] = {}
   }
   const size = Object.keys(acc[ledgetBudgetType]).length
   acc[size] = item
   
   return acc
}, {})
console.log("New Data :",this.new_data);
```

I have an array of objects. I want to filter data in and push it to a new object in which objects unique key which is common in objects.

Parent key will be my LedgerBudget Key. I have tried with for loops with hasOwnProperty but no Luck! Also tried with Lodash but pushing only to unique ones.

I want data formated in below format

```
new_data = {
'Salary' : {

       "0" :  {
        "Actual1920": 2379403,
        "Budget1920": 10121051.161450788,
        "CostOwner": "Dr. Ratnavat",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Salary",
        "LedgereType": "Salary-Teaching",
        "RemainingAmount": 7741648.161450788,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
       },
       "1": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 0,
        "CostOwner": "Dr. Ratnavat",
        "LedgerBudget": "Salary",
        "LedgerType": "Salary-Teaching",
        "RemainingAmount": 0
        },
        "2": {
            "Actual1920": 0,
            "Budget1920": 0,
            "CostOwner": "Dr. Ratnavat",
            "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
            "LedgerBudget": "Salary",
            "LedgereType": "Salary-Contract & Professional",
            "RemainingAmount": 0,
            "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
            },
},
"Admission" : {
    "0": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 540098.7555555556,
        "CostOwner": "Vineeta S",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Admission",
        "LedgereType": "Admission-Referral",
        "RemainingAmount": 540098.7555555556,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
        },
    "1": {
        "Actual1920": 0,
        "Budget1920": 40835.600000000006,
        "CostOwner": "Vineeta S",
        "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
        "LedgerBudget": "Admission",
        "LedgereType": "Admission-Others",
        "RemainingAmount": 40835.600000000006,
        "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA"
        },
}
```

}

Comment: That is NOT an array, it is an object with children (and that last comma make that object invalid).  Please add the code you have tried so we can help you fix it.

Comment: [Code which I have tried - Screenshot] (https://imgur.com/4WIkcJC)

[Result](https://imgur.com/EUM6Zu7)

Comment: I created a snippet from your object, please add the code IN your question by editing that snippet, we are NOT going to retype it from an image.( I will not even look at the image actually...)

Comment: Code Snippet Added with My Code

Comment: I suggest you make your data an array because those numbered object properties are gaining you zero over using an array with numeric indices. That way you get to use all the array functions like map, filter, find, reduce a lot more easily.

Comment: Then how should I do it with Array ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help you

```
const new_data = Object.keys(con_data).reduce( (acc,currentKey)=>{

   const item = con_data[currentKey]
   const ledgetBudgetType = item.LedgerBudget

   if( !acc[ledgetBudgetType] ){
     acc[ledgetBudgetType] = {}
   }

   const size = Object.keys(acc[ledgetBudgetType]).length

   acc[ledgetBudgetType][size] = item

   return acc

}, {})
```

Keep in mind that your `con_data` variable is an object, not an array (because of that you need to use Object.keys or Object.entries to iterate over it)

Comment: [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/EUM6Zu7) 

It gives data like this...Child data, not pushing in a parent

Comment: I've fixed the answer, a key path was missing

Comment: @ViralPatel No screenshots please. Paste the relevant code/data structures instead or create a jsfiddle of the issue.